# Outlook 'Flow' AppBuilder issues - Branching Condition Not Satisfied

Tags: outlook, mailmerge, powerapps

**tl;dr - approval settings not working in Outlook Flow**

Of 130 staff, I need to when they leave who has returned all their kit. My Column is titled 'Further Action Required.'

I want to set up a weekly email which, if this cell is set to 'Yes', emails the area manager asking them if kit has been returned. Answer is 'Yes' or 'No'.

If they click 'Yes', it emails me and other staff, it also overwrites the cell so that next time it runs, it doesn't email them.

If they hit 'No', I get a notification, nothing happens and it triggers the following week.

I created the whole thing - it doesn't work. So I pared it down to test different areas and it doesn't seem to like the condition for approval....I get Bad Request error, a branch condition not satisfied error and condition failed error. Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Flow error:

[image: Flow error]

Edit view:

[image: Edit view]

Point of clarity - it sent the approval email (I tried the 'Select Options' version but doesn't send any follow up email).

Then I select 'Yes' (returned kit)

and it returns the 'no' (kit not returned) email and then throws up the error above.

When I select No, it does the same....

Comment: When you say "it doesn't seem to like the condition for approval" do you mean the condition for sending the initial email to the area managers?  Or do you mean conditionally handling the "yes/no" response the area managers give you.

Comment: Also welcome to SO!  :D  And feel free to split this question into two parts if there's more than one error (though from the **tl;dr** edit at the top it sounds like it's just one problem now?

Comment: Also the question title includes "Branching Condition Not Satisfied".  Is this an error that you received?  If so can you post a screen shot of that too please?

Comment: Actually I see that error message "ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisified" under the "Send Approval Email" section.  Looks like your condition 2 is just skipped as the send email "run after" step returned "skipped" instead of "succeeded".   You sure the email is sent?  If so do you get the error once you've clicked a response in the email?

Comment: Hi AJP, thanks for the welcome and for the questions.

Comment: Q1:
So Step 1 - Recurrance seems fine, as does Step 2 Get Rows. Step 3 Apply To Each seems to be where the error is. After Step 3a Send Approval Email, Step 3b Conditions 2 seems to be the spot throwing up errors

Q2:
: )
I'm a fool. The word should have read *not* rather than *now*, have amended.

Q3:
Not sure I can add a screen shot to an edit, will see if I can find out how. For now: https://ibb.co/i0EXMa

Comment: Q4 - I get the approval email, if I click Yes, I get the response for if I clicked no...

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit late to this thread, but for future inquiries, I believe the YES/NO button does not actually function with the words "Yes" or "No." I was getting this same error until I changed the button to a choice and added in my option "Completed."  I then changed the condition to look for the word "Completed," and the e-mail was sent.  However, when I made the change to choice, I noticed that the field then classified the previous "Yes" option as "1".  Thus, it is my take that the "YES/NO" button is actually looking for the words "1" or "0".  And if you, like I had, input the word "Yes" into the condition, it fails because it doesn't find it.  I did not test this idea, though, since "Completed" works for my needs.